# Try to rescan with re.scanner if "False"

Tags: python, regex

How can I get `re.Scanner` to attempt next options?

I have some nested groups. When we return None, we skip over this text.

Is there a way within the function I have the scanner retry next rules (i.e. have the function hit, but not produce output, and retry matching)?

Since we cannot have negative lookahead I was thinking that it would be useful in the function itself to communicate to the scanner to be allowed to try the next rules.

```
s = re.Scanner([
   ("a", retry_under_some_conditions),   # I want to try the next rule, "aa"
   ("aa", None)                          # essentially means skip over "aa"
])

s.scan("aa")  # output should not be from retry function, but "None"; it matches on "aa".
```

This is not the actual problem, but it is related enough (just don't try to solve this actual problem in a traditional way). Being able to apply next rules would be very powerful.

I'm now thinking it might not be possible. If the regex engine optimization can only match in a straightforward way and does a complete parse, and only afterwards applies the functions, then this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get re.Scanner to attempt next options?

Short answer: You can't.

> Since we cannot have negative lookahead

I'm a bit puzzled. Because you can:

```
(r"a(?!a)", retry_under_some_conditions)
```

That would work, and the scanner would try the next rule. So I'm assuming the reason you can't, has something to do with your project / actual problem.

> I have some nested groups. When we return None, we skip over this text.

That's just because of how the scanner works. When creating the scanner it takes your patterns, in this case `a` and `aa`. These would be combined into `(a)|(aa)`. The subpattern is the important part because it relates to how the scanner works.

If we instead take the negative lookahead into account, and use this pattern `(a(?!a))|(aa)`. Then doing this:

```
string = "a aa"
pattern = r"(a(?!a))|(aa)"

for match in re.finditer(pattern, string):
    print(match.lastindex, match.span(), match.group())
```

Would print:

> 1 (0, 1) a
>
> 2 (2, 4) aa

The key here is that the scanner leverages `match.lastindex`, to map back to get the callback or value to return as a result.

> I'm now thinking it might not be possible

Without using the lookahead or some other way to make it try the next subpattern. Then this isn't possible. Neither with the scanner or regex in general. The engine matches the first subpattern, if it matches then the others are skipped. Call it a limitation of regex if you will, but that's just how regex works.

The solution would then be to make your own scanner and scan each pattern individually.

Comment: Thanks a lot for walking through it. I thought that the scanner couldn't deal with groups? I have no idea why I was thinking that... it just seems possible now.